# SES detect new email coming and do something

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I want to create a simple system like this

- Using SES to receive email (no need sending email)
- Once new email coming, get email body and POST to another Api.

Anyone know what is the technical to do something like that?

Comment: See: [Email receiving with Amazon SES - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html). If you have a _specific_ problem implementing your solution, please add the details to your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer now.

- Config SES to accept receiving emails
- Using S3 as email server to store emails.

On Email Receiving configuration (`AWS console`), Create rules set when new email coming and do 2 things

- Store email to `s3 bucket`
- Trigger `Lambda` function. Lambda function can read `messageId` but could not read email `body`, so need to use `messageId` as a `Bucket Key` and get body from `s3 Bucket`.
- Do something you want with email body.

##### Code for `lambda` function to read email body. Other steps are no need any code, just setting on `AWS console`

```
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const bucket = "email-storing-bucket-name";

async function getS3Object (bucketKey) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const getObjectCommand = new AWS.GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucket, Key: bucketKey });

    try {
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({});
        const response = await s3.send(getObjectCommand);
        let responseDataChunks = [];
        response.Body.once('error', err => reject(err));
        
        response.Body.on('data', chunk => responseDataChunks.push(chunk));
        
        response.Body.once('end', () => resolve(responseDataChunks.join('')));
    } catch (err) {
        return reject(err);
    } 
  });
}

export const handler = async(event, context) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    
    const bucketKey = event.Records[0].ses.mail.messageId 
    
    console.log("email bucketKey == ", bucketKey);
    
    await getS3Object(bucketKey).then(data => {
        console.log("data ==", data);
        // TODO: Call webhook or do anything with email body here
    });
};
```

Hope this help someone else.